# Misunderstood object instantiation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reference, instantiation

I have the following **code snippet** for primitives array instantiation

```
int[] a = new int[] {10, 20, 30}
```

Is it possible to do the same for any **Object Array** instantiation ?
Something like ..

```
 public class MyObject {
     int a;
     char b;
 }
```

And then:

```
 public class Main(){
     public static void main(String[] args){
         MyObject[] = new MyObject[] { {10, 'a'}, {20, 'b'}}
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it was really helpful ! Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Not implicitly. You would have to **use constructor for the initialization of each object**. Here is an example:

```
public class Example {

    static class MyObject {
        int a;
        char b;

        public MyObject(int a, char b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject[] objs = new MyObject[] {new MyObject(10, 'a'), new MyObject (20, 'b')};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write the appropriate constructor in the `MyObject` class (which takes `int` and `char` arguments and initializes the members `a` and `b`) and then initialize the array with:

```
MyObject[] arr = new MyObject[] {new MyObject(10, 'a'), new MyObject (20, 'b')};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare one constructor in the class.

```
public class MyObject {
   int a;
   char b;
   MyObject(int a, char b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
   }
}
```

After that you can initialize array like this

```
MyObject[] somedamn = new MyObject[] { new MyObject(10,'a'), new MyObject(20,'b')};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a contructor in your `MyObject` class:

```
public MyObject(int x, char c) {
    // comment: set them equal to the variables you put up in your MyObject class already
}
```

Then you can create an object in your `Main` class:

```
MyObject object1 = new MyObject(10, 'a');
```

Then place `object1` in the array: `array[0] = object1`.

Or you can can store the `new MyObject(10, 'a')` directly into the array - but it might be a bit harder to understand if you are new to it.